# Java method not exiting properly with return statement

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am beginning to write a function for a binary tree. The method is currently aiming to find the node in the tree and return the node. The root value is data and the left and right are subtrees. When I step through it in the debugger when it gets to the return statement it jumps back into the second if block and will end up returning null.

```
@Override
public T successor(T d) {



T datas = null;

    if (d.compareTo(this.data) < 0) //If its less than the root
        left.successor(d);

    if (d.compareTo(this.data) > 0) //If its less than the root
        right.successor(d);


    if (d.equals(this.data)){ //We found the node
        datas = this.data;
    }

    return datas;
}
```

Comment: how and how many times do you call this method? an execution of a return does not return to a previous line of the same method.

Comment: The second if statement recursively calls right.successor. So if you're returning from a recursive call, then you will end up at the end of that if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the returned value from the recursive call and end up return a *null* (datas) at a particular point in the call stack.

Change you code as:

```
T datas = null;

if (d.compareTo(this.data) < 0) //If its less than the root
    datas = left.successor(d);

if (d.compareTo(this.data) > 0) //If its less than the root
    datas = right.successor(d);


if (d.equals(this.data)){ //We found the node
    datas = this.data;
}

return datas;
```

Or, you can remove the local variable and simplify it as

```
if (d.compareTo(this.data) < 0) {
    return left.successor(d);
} else if (d.compareTo(this.data) > 0) {
    return right.successor(d);
} 
return this.data;
```

UPDATE: This assumes the value being searched for exists. You have to take care when left/right is null.

Comment: I think the last line of the second example should be `return this.data;`. Shouldn't it?